# Multi-Truecrypt, One unencrypted

Tags: encryption, multi-boot, truecrypt

My goal is to create a multi-boot system in which I have an unencrypted Windows XP\7 for guests and and an encrypted Windows 7 for me with WUBI installed on this partition if possible.  Truecrypt doesn't appear to support these configurations.  My original goal was to create a hidden OS, but this wouldn't allow for dual booting Linux and Windows (I didn't want to use WUBI at the time) and I didn't like the way Truecrypt partitioned my disk space.  I kind of like WUBI now :).  I basically want:

Unencrypted partition:
Windows 7 or XP (XP preferred due to conserve disk space)

Encrypted partition:
Windows 7, w\ WUBI strongly preferred

I do not have to use Truecrypt, if the solution is to load a small Linux environment, un DM-Crypt a partition, then chain into BOOTMGR so be it.